# Mockito spy throws stubbing exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to spy restTemplate and I wanna to stub 'exchange' method

Here is some code:

spying class

```
@Bean
  fun mockedRestTemplate(): RestTemplate = Mockito.spy(RestTemplate::class.java)
```

another class

```
   val headers = HttpHeaders()
   headers.setBasicAuth(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString())

   val responseBody = "some error message"

   val ex = HttpClientErrorException.create(
        HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        "random",
        headers,
        responseBody.toByteArray(),
        Charset.defaultCharset()
    )

   val httpEntity = HttpEntity(Any(), headers)

   Mockito.doThrow(ex).`when`(restTemplate).exchange(
            any() ?: config.randomEndpoint,
            any(HttpMethod::class.java) ?: HttpMethod.POST,
            any() ?: httpEntity,
            any() ?: Foo::class.java
   )
```

What might I be doing wrong here? I get this error message:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at test.suites.controller.FooTest.canGetFailedErrorFieldsIfApiRejectsRequest(FooTest.kt:468)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

When I'm mocking/spying another classes, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Matchers, such as `any()`, must be used only in `verify()` calls. You have:

```
val httpEntity = HttpEntity(Any(), headers)
```

You can't use `any()` in this context as you are constructing an object, not verifying a method call. You need to pass in an actual value here.

Side note: `spy()` is intended to wrap a real instance. If you're just mocking out an interface (`RestTemplate`) you should likely be using `mock(RestTemplate::class.java)` instead.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not fixing the issue. I wanted to wrap real instance, so I could mock only some certain methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, but I still didn't get the reason. The issue was in config.randomEndpoint.  When I changed the value to string type without injecting config class, the error disappeared.